# css selector issue with valid and nested invalid

Tags: javascript, html, css, queryselector

I am currently trying to figure out the following situation.

```js
const invalidInput = document.querySelector('.ng-invalid:not(.no-check, .ng-invalid *)');

console.log(invalidInput.name);
```

```html
<div class="ng-valid no-check">
  <div class="ng-invalid">
    <span>(</span>
    <input class="ng-invalid" name="hello" id="hello">
    <span>)</span>
    <input class="ng-invalid" name="hello2" id="hello2">
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<input class="ng-invalid" name="hello3" id="hello3">
```

the output should log hello3

here is the fiddle : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/natdrip/jLgd5woe/41/)

Comment: Is your `input` directly in `body` or is there any other parent element?

Comment: the input is nested within other elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `input` is inside a `div` container, you can get your un-nested element by using direct child selector `>`:

```js
const invalidInput = document.querySelector('.container > .ng-invalid:not(.no-check)');

console.log(invalidInput.name);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="ng-valid no-check">
    <div class="ng-invalid">
      <span>(</span>
      <input class="ng-invalid" name="hello" id="hello">
      <span>)</span>
      <input class="ng-invalid" name="hello2" id="hello2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <input class="ng-invalid" name="hello3" id="hello3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `input.ng-invalid:not(div.ng-invalid .ng-invalid)`

Where you are getting all `input.ng-invalid` that aren't a child of a div with the class of `.ng-invalid`.

```js
const ngInvalid = document.querySelector('input.ng-invalid:not(div.ng-invalid .ng-invalid)');
console.log(ngInvalid.name)
```

```html
<div class="ng-valid no-check">
  <div class="ng-invalid">
    <span>(</span>
    <input class="ng-invalid" name="hello" id="hello">
    <span>)</span>
    <input class="ng-invalid" name="hello2" id="hello2">
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<input class="ng-invalid" name="hello3" id="hello3">
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated the script to include some extra details. First, `querySelectorAll()` to determine if the selector was pulling multiple items. Yes. Then I logged the tagname and full classlist.
Your selector is essentially retrieving items with class `.ng-invalid` that are NOT nested within elements with that class and do not have `.no-check`. This matches two items: the first div with ng-invalid and the final input. You are only returning one element, the first one, which is the div. I would suggest adding an "input" tag to your selector, like so.

```js
const invalidInput = document.querySelectorAll('input.ng-invalid:not(.no-check, .ng-invalid *)');

console.log([...invalidInput].map(i => `${i.tagName}: ${i.classList.value}`));
```

```html
<div class="ng-valid no-check">
  <div class="ng-invalid">
    <span>(</span>
    <input class="ng-invalid" name="hello" id="hello">
    <span>)</span>
    <input class="ng-invalid" name="hello2" id="hello2">
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<input class="ng-invalid" name="hello3" id="hello3">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking for `input` elements, then you can filter something like this:

```js
const invalidInputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('input.ng-invalid')].filter(el => !closestWithoutSelf(el, '.ng-invalid'));

function closestWithoutSelf(el, selector) {
  let parentEl = el.parentElement;
  while (parentEl) {
    if (parentEl.matches(selector)) {
      return parentEl;
    }
    parentEl = parentEl.parentElement;
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(invalidInputs);
```

```html
<div class="ng-valid no-check">
  <div class="ng-invalid">
    <span>(</span>
    <input class="ng-invalid" name="hello" id="hello">
    <span>)</span>
    <input class="ng-invalid" name="hello2" id="hello2">
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<input class="ng-invalid" name="hello3" id="hello3">
```